# Is there a way to set a state with textinput when onChangeText is already in use?

Tags: react-native

Im trying to set a state with the values from a textinput (which is a reusable component), Im using `onChangeText` to `setFieldValue` (`useFormikContext()`), I also want to set a state which will be sending to the Parent component. I tried using `onChange` but noticed it saves the text without the last word/number, for instance if I type 0123456789, the `setFieldValue` gets 0123456789, but the other one (with `onChange`) gets only 012345678 (without 9).

Here is the code:

```
function AppFormField({ name, width, childToParent, ...otherProps }) {
  const { setFieldTouched, setFieldValue, errors, touched, values } =
    useFormikContext();

    
  
     
  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
        onBlur={() => setFieldTouched(name)}
        onChangeText={(text) => setFieldValue(name, text)}
        onChange={() => childToParent(bn)}
        value={values[name]}
        width={width}
        {...otherProps}
      />
      <ErrorMessage error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Parent Component:

```
...

const [bn, setBN] = useState("");

  const childToParent = (childdata) => {
    setBN(childdata);
    console.log(childdata);
  };
  console.log("bn");
  console.log(bn);


...

 return (
```

...

```
<UppFormField
              keyboardType="numeric"
              autoCorrect={false}
              // icon="bank"
              name="acct_number"
              placeholder="Account Number"
              style={{ paddingRight: 50 }}
              childToParent={childToParent}
            />

...
)
```

Comment: How `childToParent(bn)` looks like? And what is `bn`?

Comment: Okay thank you. I will edit the question so you see the Parent component.

Comment: Ok I see your `childToParent`. Question: if `bn` is the parent state, why you use `bn` as input parameter of `childToParent`? This step is not clear. Could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Make a middle function called

```
const onTextChange = (text) => {
  setFieldValue(text)
  parentFunction(text)
}
```

then TextInput takes has

```
onChangeText={onTextChange}
```